# Can I connect to a device thats connected to another vpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, nas

i have a Unifi USG-3P, with a L2TP VPN Server setup where i connect to access my local devices

I also have a Synology NAS, this NAS connects to ExpressVPN via OpenVPN and allows to be set as a gateway on devices, so does devices go through the NAS VPN Connection.

My problem is when NAS connects to VPN, i cant access the devices that have NAS ip as gateway. Through my L2TP VPN. If i turn off NAS VPN connection then i am able to ping does devices.

How would i be able to access does devices while my device connects to my Unifi Gateway VPN and NAS to ExpressVPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing normally traffic from local devices to VPN clients flows like this:

```
local device [default route]--> Synology NAS [default route]--> USG-3P --> VPN client
```

When the Synology NAS has a VPN connection active – which deliberately changes the default route – all replies that your local devices send to L2TP VPN devices are no longer routed through the USG-3P but instead through ExpressVPN (where they vanish into the void).

To prevent this, configure a *more specific* route on the Synology NAS that would route the L2TP VPN client address range through the USG-3P as gateway.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. This worked, sorry i a fairly new to all of this, i knew i was missing something simple.